# Fit several predictions plots of sjPlot in one window

Tags: r, graph, sjplot

I've come across a problem when using sjPlot using the "pred" function.
With the model I currently have, three predictors are used in the model.

```
NQuart3.1 <- 
  glmmTMB(Pos_count ~ Predsumscale + Buildscale + 
          (1|Territory),
          offset = log(Ndays),
          dispformula = ~Roadscale + Buildscale, 
          data = NightQuart3, 
          family = nbinom1(link = "log")
          )
```

when I use sjplot on this, it will provide me with 2 separate graphs.
One for Buildscale and one for Predsumscale, separated.

```
plot_model(NQuart3.1, type = "pred",
           title = "Wolf space use night estimates April - June",
           axis.title  = "Wolf GPS locations")

$Predsumscale
(http://127.0.0.1:26952/graphics/ede13814-0fa4-4ba3-8c20-ae47c68dcabc.png)
$Buildscale 
(http://127.0.0.1:26952/graphics/fe656c83-5bb0-4692-ad35-dd23a7ce3f0a.png)
```

I was wondering if you can adjust the code so that it would combine both graphs in one plot window?

Not combined but just side-by-side.

This would make it a lot easier to compare models with multiple parameters.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can we please have a [mcve]? There are a lot of packages that provide the capability of arranging several grid (==lattice/ggplot/etc) graphics in one window (`latticeExtra`, `cowplot`, `patchwork` ...)

Comment: Any model with several fixed variables will produce the outcome I have done here with sjPlot. I checked latticeExtra, cowplot and patchwork. I'm looking for something as in latticeExtra but with sjPlot. In this example, sjPlot produces 2 plots, I still need these same plots, but I was wondering if there is a way to alter the coding so that those plots are not shown in a separate window when seeing the output in R. Rather I would like to show them both, side -by -side in the same plot window in R

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to tell `plot_model()` explicitly "please put all of these in the same plot window", but there are many easy ways to take the plot object and render the components within a single window with different layouts.

Setup:

```r
library(glmmTMB)
m1 <- glmmTMB(mpg ~ disp + hp, mtcars)
library(sjPlot)
pp <- plot_model(m1, type = "pred")
```

`sjPlot` has a `plot_grid()`, but it doesn't seem very flexible.

```r
sjPlot::plot_grid(pp)
```

or

```r
gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs=pp)
```

`cowplot` has a `plot_grid()` with many more options

```r
cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = pp)
```

`patchwork` is probably the most flexible.

```r
library(patchwork)
pp[[1]] + pp[[2]]
```